# didSelectRowAtIndex doesn't scrollToRowAtIndex until 2nd tap

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a static tableview that shows a date picker when the appropriate cell is selected. The didSelectRowAtIndexPath triggers the show/hide of the date picker cell; however, it's not until the second selection that scrollToRow is executed and the picker cell is hidden.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

   if (cell == self.dateCell){
       self.dateOpen = !self.isdateOpen;
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Any Ideas of where I've gone astray??
Thank You!!

EDIT: I forgot to add, it's the last row that's expanding with the date cell... I'm wondering how that would affect it. Although, I did just copy/paste a few cells to make it not the last row and it didn't help.

Comment: try reversing the order of `[self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: nope... same behavior. I should add, it's the last cell of the tableView who's cell height goes from 0 to 168.